# MassTransit JobConsumer sample fails with timeout exception

Tags: masstransit

MassTransit to 7.0.4.  I'm getting an exception back trying to demo the most basic Job Consumer scenario in place as described here: https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/job-consumers.html.  Exception message is:

```
Timeout waiting for response, RequestId: 4ec50000-294e-000c-71b6-08d8768d0bc0
```

I suspect that the example may be missing Conductor configuration.

I have a solution with 3 projects.  Project TestJob holds the `ConvertVideo` interface to share between the client and consumer:

```
namespace JobSystem.Jobs
{
    using System;

    public interface ConvertVideo
    {
        Guid VideoId { get; }
        string Format { get; }
    }
}
```

Project TestJobClient has a single class, Program.  The exception comes up in the call to GetResponse.

```
namespace JobSystemClient
{
    using System;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using JobSystem.Jobs;
    using MassTransit;
    using MassTransit.Contracts.JobService;

    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main()
        {
            var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg => 
            {
                // Not in sample, I added this
                cfg.Host("localhost");
            });

            var source = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

            await busControl.StartAsync(source.Token);
            try
            {
                var serviceClient = busControl.CreateServiceClient();

                var requestClient = serviceClient.CreateRequestClient<ConvertVideo>();

                do
                {
                    string value = await Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter video format (or quit to exit)");
                        Console.Write("> ");
                        return Console.ReadLine();
                    });

                    if ("quit".Equals(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        break;

                    // Exception comes up here!
                    var response = await requestClient.GetResponse<JobSubmissionAccepted>(new
                    {
                        VideoId = NewId.NextGuid(),
                        Format = value
                    });
                }
                while (true);
            }
            finally
            {
                await busControl.StopAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Project TestJobConsumer has two classes, Program and ConvertVideoJobConsumer.  I added a wee bit of code here to start the bus and ensure it stays alive to process requests.

```
namespace JobSystemConsoleService
{
    using System;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using JobSystem.Jobs;
    using MassTransit;
    using MassTransit.Conductor;
    using MassTransit.JobService;

    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main()
        {
            var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
            {
                // Not in sample, I added this
                cfg.Host("localhost");

                var options = new ServiceInstanceOptions()
                    .EnableInstanceEndpoint();

                cfg.ServiceInstance(options, instance =>
                {
                    instance.ConfigureJobServiceEndpoints();

                    var queueName = instance.EndpointNameFormatter.Consumer<ConvertVideoJobConsumer>();

                    instance.ReceiveEndpoint(queueName, e =>
                    {
                        e.Consumer(() => new ConvertVideoJobConsumer(), c =>
                        {
                            // Note: edited this line from options to opts, as 
                            // the example has a compile-time error due to options 
                            // in already existing one of the parent scopes
                            c.Options<JobOptions<ConvertVideo>>(opts => opts
                                .SetJobTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15))
                                .SetConcurrentJobLimit(10));
                        });
                    });
                });
            });

            await busControl.StartAsync();

            Console.WriteLine("Hit <Enter> to quit.");
            Console.Write("> ");
            Console.ReadLine();

            await busControl.StopAsync();
        }

        public class ConvertVideoJobConsumer :
            IJobConsumer<ConvertVideo>
        {
            public async Task Run(JobContext<ConvertVideo> context)
            {
                // simulate converting the video
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

*UPDATE 2020-Dec-15:*

As suggested, I tried to get the sample app running properly so I can compare the code there to the documentation - but I haven't been able to get the sample to run properly.

As downloaded, it runs fine - and the first call to the service using the Swagger UI always succeeds. My second or third call consistently fails however - looks like a PostgreSQL locking error.  Changing the sample to use SQL Server instead corrects this.

---

*UPDATE 2020-Dec-17:*

The documentation sample appears to be missing configuration around the definitions of JobSaga, JobTypeSaga and JobAttemptSaga, as well as information on the related repositories.

My sample is running on .NET Framework 4.8, which means trying to mimick the JobConsumer sample won't work because MassTransit.EntityFramework has a dependency on .NET standard 2.1.

Moved over to MassTransit.NHibernate, which only requires .NET Standard 2.0.

Still working on it...

Comment: You might compare it to the [official sample](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-JobConsumers) and look for differences.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson The documentation on the project site isn't "official"?

Comment: @ChrisPatterson I mean, I will... But I was looking for the simplest possible setup to get something working, and then build up to my current usage from there (I'm migrating from using Turnarounds), and I had assumed that the project docs would provide some guidance.

Comment: I guess my point being, I don't see anything wrong with the above, so I suggested trying the sample to see if that works for you. Then look for differences. You're welcome to submit a PR to fix the documentation if you find out where they don't match.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson I appreciate the clarification. I'm changing gears for the time being, but I'll get back to this shortly and see what I can't find.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson If you don't mind my asking...  I'm spending some time on this today, two things jump out at me: The sample app has configuration for the 3 Saga types, while the docs don't. Also, sample app includes migrations to create db tables for the saga type repositories, while the docs don't.  Are these accidental omissions from the docs, or is it related to configuration choices made there?

Comment: @ChrisPatterson For what it's worth, my other initial issue that I've found is that my install of RabbitMQ did not have the 'rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange' plugin.

Comment: I didn't document the migrations, but that's part of using EF Core and up to your application to include them. That's why I used it in the sample, to show how to do it.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson I'm using framework version 4.8, so I couldn't use EFCore if I wanted to, since the integration package requires .Net Standard 2.1. So I've been digging into how to configure the sagas and saga repositories for NHibernate integration.  Seems to me that mapping of JobSaga.Job can't be shared outside of EFCore currently due to its use of JsonValueConverter, and I haven't been able to find any mapping code in MassTransit for any persistence mechanisms in MassTransit (so far) asides from EFCore. Am I wrong?

Comment: Out of the box? Azure Table Storage is supported. I'm not positive, but it should work with any of the document-based repositories like MongoDB or Cosmos.